# Check for a matrix ortogonality

Tags: matrices, orthogonality

I have seen a few example but they all deal with both positive and negative numbers so the product nicely can be 
$0$.

However, what about a matrix like this:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4\\2&3&4&1\\3&4&1&2\\4&1&2&3\end{bmatrix}$$

How can I prove that it is orthogonal?

Comment: You would have to show that the columns/rows are orthonormal vectors. Or you could show that the inverse of the above matrix is its transpose. If these things are not true, then the matrix is not orthogonal. Check out this link:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix

Comment: Just observe that none of the rows/columns is a unit vector...

Comment: @DonAntonio is that a problem? I am new to matrices and vectors.

Comment: @user970696 I'd say it is a huge problem. Read the definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix

Comment: @ DonAntonio well then again, how can I verify that this matrix is orthogonal? The only answer suggest to transpose.

Answer (score 1):

Matrix is orthogonal if its transpose equals its inverse. Thus, find the transpose of your matrix and then multiply the transpose with the original matrix. If the result is the identity matrix, your original matrix was orthogonal. Otherwise your matrix is not orthogonal.

Comment: When I transpose  (transposed one is the same as original) and multiply the matrix in question, the result has 14s in the diagonal and 11s in the remaining cells.

Comment: @user970696 Well, is that the identity matrix?

Comment: Hint: opposite of yes.